# Subqueries in createQueryBuilder method

Tags: php, symfony, orm, subquery

I've SQL query looking like this below:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM (
    SELECT m.*
    FROM game m
    WHERE m.date > :date
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT m.*
    FROM game m
    LEFT JOIN bet b ON b.game_id = m.ID
    WHERE b.user_id = :user
) AS t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

I am writing a small project in Symfony 5.2 with ORM 2.8 and I wonder how to pass the above query using queryBuilder.

Writing first subquery is simple

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('g')
    ->where('g.date > :val')
    ->setParameter('val', new \DateTime())
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

But how put it in subquery, and left join other one?

Comment: Do you want only subquery in left join or also in from?

Comment: I'm interested for whole query